# Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany::$path

Tags: laravel

I wrote a relation belongsToMany between products and photos and now I want to show products in the home page. I did it like so:

```
@foreach ($latestProducts as $product)
  <img src="{{$product->photos()->path}}">
@endforeach
```

homeController:

```
public function index()
    {
        $latestProducts = Product::orderBy('created_at' , 'desc')->limit(10)->get();
        return view('front.layouts.index' , compact('latestProducts'));
    }
```

photo model:

```
public function products() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class);
    }
```

product model:

```
public function photos() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Photo::class);
    }
```

I got Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany::$path .And when I write {{$product->photos[0]->path}} , the error changes to "Undefined array key 0. Also when I write {{$product->photos->path}} ,I get an error as "Property [path] does not exist on this collection instance."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you got a `photo` attribute/field in the `Photo` model. Because `photos` is a collection of photos, you might want to write:

```
@foreach ($latestProducts as $product)
    @foreach ($product->photos as $photo)
        <img src="{{$photo->path}}">
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

And only the first photo:

```
@foreach ($latestProducts as $product)
    <img src="{{$product->photos->first()->path}}">
@endforeach

// Or to be safe
@foreach ($latestProducts as $product)
    <img src="{{optional($product->photos->first())->path}}">
@endforeach

// Or this in php 8
@foreach ($latestProducts as $product)
    <img src="{{$product->photos->first()?->path}}">
@endforeach
```

Comment: This way gives me all of photos without error, but I need the first photo of each product to show in home page.

Comment: @SaharParsaifar Great, pls make this the correct answer to close this thread.

Comment: Sure. Just can you tell me why it didn't work without using "optional()"?

Comment: @SaharParsaifar I use the optional method so it will still work when a product has no photos: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-optional

Answer (score 0):

You have to use

```
{{ $product->photos->path }}
```

cause when you deal with relations in blade you  deal with it as a property of class of the father class unlike when you deal with it in eloquent ORM you can use `photos()`

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I wrote like so too , but again get a new error. "Property [path] does not exist on this collection instance."

Answer (score 0):

Basically the error is saying that there is no property photos in the $products. Assuming that the table name is correct and the foreign keys too

you can just do:

```
public function index()
{
    $latestProducts = Product::with('photos')->orderBy('created_at' , 'desc')->limit(10)->get();
    return view('front.layouts.index' , compact('latestProducts'));
}
```

And in blade file try to remove the (), because it will load the relationship.

```
@foreach ($latestProducts->photos as $product)
  <img src="{{$product->path}}">
@endforeach
```

Comment: I had done this way to. But I got the same error. I checked the tables name , fields name, relations, and all of things that I thought. But I get error yet.

Comment: post everything here please, all 3 tables and their records. It's hard without debugging.
Also run php artisan cache:clear or php artisan optimize
I also edited it, give it a try.